# creating an object, then using a function to display the contents of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I dont really have anything to start with -- I am a BEGINNER and am struggling with basic JavaScript concepts.  Any guidance?  I am hoping to display the information in a table or list in a Div

This is my super rough start:
I think I want to use a nested array to create an object with properties.  Then I make a function and in it I think that I need to use appendChild to create the table in the div....and somehow I need to display the content in the div...Im pretty lost.

```
<script>
var personalInfo = [
    [Dog],
    [4456],
    [3 - 4456]
];

function object() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("personalInfo");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("theList").appendChild(node);
}
</script>

<div id="theDiv">
<ul id="theList"></ul></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide proper sample or the code that you have tried.

Comment: *"I think I want to use a nested array to create an object with properties."* Uh? Why do you use an array if you want to create an object? Maybe the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) helps you.

Comment: one more thing if you are including some string like Dog here enclose them in quotes else javascript will consider as variable (that will be undefined here)

Comment: Thank you SO much to everyone who has participated! This all has helped me a whole lot and I think I can get it from here.  I appreciate the help so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using an object map than an array.  That way you can give each field a meaningful name.

```
var personalInfo = {
    name: "Dave",
    ext: 3086, 
    desk: "5-5715"
};
```

You can also loop through the properties using:

```
for (var key in personalInfo) {
    var val = personalInfo[key];
    // add to document
}
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/XjWzp/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a for loop of the persnalInfo

```
<script>
    var personalInfo = ["Dave", "3086", "5-5715" ]; 
    function object() { 
     for(var i=0;i<personalInfo.length;i++){
         var node=document.createElement("li"); 

         node.innerHTML=personalInfo[i]; 
         document.getElementById("theList").appendChild(node); 
     }
    }</script> 
    <div id="theDiv"> 
      <ul id="theList"> 
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the script in different file or at the end of document otherwise it will try to find

```
document.getElementById("theList")
```

event before it is created

Create object as specified by McGarnagle and then you need to call object on document ready or just include in script

```
function object() { .... }

object()
```